# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0, 1, 2,3 in same line

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined

I am getting this PHP error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\MYBLOG\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MYBLOG\admin\library\engines\typography-engine.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\MYBLOG\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MYBLOG\admin\library\engines\typography-engine.php on line 32

Here is the PHP code that throws it:

```
/* Check stored against current to make sure we don't display deleted css */
if(is_array($custom_fonts)):
    foreach($custom_fonts as $id => $font):
        if(!$current_custom[$id])unset($custom_fonts[$id]);
    endforeach;
endif;    
$css = '';
```

LINE 32 IS HERE:

```
   if(!$current_custom[$id])unset($custom_fonts[$id]);
```

What does this error mean? What causes this error?
Is there a quick fix to resolve these error?
Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the 32 line with this:

```
if(empty($current_custom[$id]) || !$current_custom[$id])unset($custom_fonts[$id]);
```

There is not a real problem, only a notice (=advice, not error, not warning) which tells you that the $id does not actually exists in the $current_custom array. As the coded tries to unsed the $current_custom[$id] if it is evaluated as false (null, zero, empty string, ...) it is just fine.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Mvorisek

Comment: You are welcome. If this answers your question, please accept this post as answer.